# PHP Script that emails me when a 500 error is encountered

Tags: php

On my Classic ASP sites, I have a script that uses Server.GetLastError to output the file, line and error message when a 500 error is encountered. This is then emailed to me so I can then use it to debug & fix the code.

Edit: to be clear, the Classic ASP solution uses a custom 500 page to send the details...

Is there something similar in PHP I can use for the same function?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2146171/2663825

Comment: Wrap your code in try/catch, register an exception handler, have the handler send you an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, there are some third party applications out there that do that for you, like New Relic or AppNeta. These 2 are the ones I heard about/used, there are others as well.
Or you can make your own, but I think that @Dexa's comment will only show you PHP related errors, and not server wide (apache, mysql...)
The tools above can be configured to monitor other services.

LE: PHP uses several servers, for Apache you can use something like: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html

`ErrorDocument 500 /500.php`

For nginx you can use something like: [nginx configure default error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162274/nginx-configure-default-error-pages)

In the file 500.php you can use the mail function.